# How can I have different configuration for the job and one of it's run

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I configured a job on Jenkins which trigger some script in python and does some tests. In the end, it gives results inside an artifact folder (so we can keep X amount of results at any time), which I am showing presenting with a `Publish rich text message` post-build action. Here is the pretty straight forward code:

```
<br/>
<h2>Results:</h2>
<iframe src=./artifact/artifacts/results.html width=1100 height=1000></iframe>
```

This works correctly inside a job build, but if you go inside the main page of the job, I get a `404 not found` since it cannot find the file. I understand that the error is correct, since it cannot find any artifact folder if we are not within a build of the said job. My question is how can I have different settings depending if we are inside the main page of the job vs a build of the job ?

I checked online and found that there is a `lastSuccessfulBuild` variable I can use but then I think it will show the same results no matter which build we are, which is something I do not want.